# Displaying text in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm totally new in Thymeleaf. Just read about it earlier, now, I'm trying to display some text using Thymeleaf in the front end, getting the values from Spring MVC in back-end.

File `successPwd.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Password Change</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <h2>Password Changed</h2>
 Your password has been changed. Your account information is below.

 Username: [[${account.username}]] <br/>
 First Name: [[${account.firstName}]] <br/>
 Last Name: [[${account.surname}]] <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

File `PasswordResetController.java`

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/user/new_password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveNewPassword(@RequestParam(value="new_password",required=false) String password, @RequestParam(value="hash") String hash, Model model)

{
    //some codes to check hash
    AccountInfo account = accountInfoService.getAccount(hash);
    model.addAttribute("account", account);
    return "/successPwd";
}
```

What I'm getting is like this:

```
Password Changed

Your password has been changed. Your account information is below. 
Username: [[${account.username}]] 
First Name: [[${account.firstName}]] 
Last Name: [[${account.surname}]]
```

Thymeleaf is not converting to the proper values, most likely I missed something very very basic here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, you should use `th:text`. For example, `Username: <p th:text=${account.username}>Username will be rendered here</p>`. Note that, the text inside `p` tag won't be shown.

See here for more details: [Standard thymeleaf syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax)

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out after some trial and error, but it seems awkward that it needs to be on a <p> tag. Or maybe I just don't fully understand thymeleaf yet.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get rid of the "awkward" Html tag you can do as follows.

```
<span th:text="${account.username}" th:remove="tag">userName</span>
```